# Significance of Data

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

The following is a result I get from a pair trading model. I am trying to figure out the significance of the below but failing. Can someone help me out i.e. a resource or possibly an explanation on the significance/result of this:

---

Results Summary (Test 1)

Data: 
Effective sample size: 58583
Model: H1
Lags: 1
Statistic: trace
Significance level: 0.05

## r  h  stat      cValue   pValue   eigVal

0  0  9.3117    15.4948  0.3847   0.0001
1  0  2.0914    3.8415   0.1483   0.0000

---

Results Summary (Test 2)

Data: 
Effective sample size: 58582
Model: H1
Lags: 2
Statistic: trace
Significance level: 0.05

## r  h  stat      cValue   pValue   eigVal

0  0  9.1995    15.4948  0.3957   0.0001
1  0  2.0402    3.8415   0.1535   0.0000

---

Thanks.

PS: I am new to quantitative analysis. Please recommend a book which would be good for an absolute newbie.

Comment: Is the question to recommend a book or to help you interpret the results? In case of the latter, then you should consider giving more details of the problem. It looks like you might be testing for stationarity of the cointegrated process (pair). It's very unclear though...

Comment: Hi Mike, Sorry I guess it is a bit vague. 

I am just trying to test a couple of stocks and see whether they can be traded as a pair. I was using the Correlation factor till now and a rate of change approach till now. Just using matlab and trying to figure out cointegration. 


The problem as I am taking it. Whether this test result proves that cointegration exists? If yes, how do I interpret the realtionship?  Thanks @GoodGuyMike